# using regex to split english alphabet and foreign letters in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

table:

```
searches
---------
๊ ufa800
0.75 ราคา บอล
1.5 2 บอล
1.5 ราคา บอล
10 เว็บ สล็อต
123bet เข้า สู่ ระบบ
123up slot
```

I tried using split part to extract the English alphabet and numbers but to no avail. Essentially I want two columns one for the original and one for the extracted English letters and numbers from the orginal and not include the foregin letters. I tried regex but i think i failed on this one.

```
select SPLIT_PART(searches,'[A-Za-z0-9]*$',1 ) as split, searches from thai
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You could phrase this using a regex replacement to strip off non alphanumeric/non space characters:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(searches, '[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+', '', 'g') AS split, searches
FROM thai;
```

Comment: thank you! But i wanna extract also the foreign language i tried this: 

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(searches, '^[^a-zA-Z0-9]*$', '', 'g') AS foreign, searches
FROM thai;
i replace the regex to a different one , but only got the original data

Comment: for foreign language try, `(searches, '[a-zA-Z0-9.]*$', '', 'g')` @johnnn

Comment: @jian i still get the original and not the foreign letter only.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/POGnI88_ @johnnn is this what you want?

Comment: @jian was able to resolved it with unicode: 
`SELECT searches as original,
REGEXP_REPLACE(searches, '[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+', '', 'g') AS english_alphabet,
REGEXP_REPLACE(searches, '[^\u0E00-\u0E7F]+', '', 'g') AS foreign

FROM thai;`